# swift: refresh/reload table view did not work

Tags: tableview, swift2, xcode7, reloaddata, uirefreshcontrol

i'm new in swift development, i added data in server tried to refresh tableviewcontroller with refreshcontrol function but value in table view didn't change.

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var sosTableView: UITableView!

var datas = [dataSos]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.labelText = "Loading"
    spinningActivity.detailsLabelText = "Please wait"
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.loadDataServer()
        spinningActivity.hide(true)
        self.sosTableView.reloadData()
    }


    //loadDataSos()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

  var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refreshData"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl
}
```

**Refresh func**

```
func refreshData(){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.loadDataServer()

        self.sosTableView.reloadData()
    }

    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

}
```

**load server func**

```
func loadDataServer(){

    do {

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://xxxx/scripts/xxx.php")!)

        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)




        //let NumberOfPersons = jsonResult.count

        // **LOOP THROUGH THE JSON ARRAY**
        for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
            let userId = anItem["userId"] as! String
            let userName = anItem["firstName"] as! String
            let userAddress = anItem["address"] as! String
            let userDate = anItem["date"] as! String
            let userLocation = anItem["location"] as! String
            var userEvent = anItem["event"] as? String
            let sosId = anItem["sosId"] as! String
            // do something with personName and personID


             let imageUrl = NSURL(string:"http://xxx")
             let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!)


            if userEvent == nil{
                userEvent = "Need Help"

            }else if userEvent! == "1" {
                userEvent! = "Thief"
            }
            else if userEvent! == "2" {
                userEvent! = "Fire"
            }
            else{
                userEvent! = "Healthy Issue"
            }



            //print(personName)
            if imageData == nil{
                let photo1 = UIImage(named: "defaultPhoto")!
                let data1 = dataSos(userId: userId, name: userName, location: userLocation, address: userAddress, event: userEvent!, date: userDate, photo: photo1, sosId: sosId)
                self.datas += [data1]
            }
            else{
            let photo1 = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            //let photo1 = UIImage(named: "defaultPhoto")
                let data1 = dataSos(userId: userId, name: userName, location: userLocation, address: userAddress, event: userEvent!, date: userDate, photo: photo1, sosId: sosId)

            self.datas += [data1]
            }
        }






    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error)

    }
   // }
}
```

**Update: table view data source**

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return datas.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cellIdentifier = "cell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let data0 = datas[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = data0.name
    cell.locationLabel.text = data0.location
    cell.addressTextView.text = data0.address
    cell.eventLabel.text = data0.event
    cell.dateLabel.text = data0.date
    cell.photoLabel.image = data0.photo
    self.roundingUIView(cell.photoLabel, cornerRadiusParam: 35)


    return cell



}
```

Comment: Can you also provide your  UITableViewDataSource protocol implementation? I mean tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: methods

Comment: hey @Iyuna,  i just added table view data source that u asked. anyway data only updated if i re-run the apps. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just understood that you're inheriting for UITableViewController, therefor you already have tableView property inherited from it. The table view from this property has already set delegate and dataSource to your controller, but not for your custom sosTableView. You should replace your custom sosTableView with inherited tableView property and then everything gonna work as you're expecting.

Comment: yeah thats what i want, what should i do?

Comment: sorry i dont get it, so i need to disconnecting reference outlets of 'sosTableView' from storyboard and turn  sosTableView.reloadData to tableView.reload data? @Iyuna

Comment: You can do one of the following: 
  
• delete sosTableView at all and use in all cases tableView property (also connect tableView property to your table view in storyboard if it's not already connected)
  
• set in storyboard your sosTableView's delegate and dataSource to your MainTableViewController

Comment: Which variant did you try?

Comment: Ok. Could you please share your code with GitHub or whatever so I can check if you have done everything correct?